# How to compare two array index and get different string?

Tags: php

I have two arrays. I want to compare these array and find different string of them.
Ex.

```
$a = array('a','c','b','e','x');
$b = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
```

I want string which is not common in both array.

Comment: http://php.net/array_diff

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array_diff)

Doing this will show you what values are present in `$b` but not `$a`

```
array_diff($b, $a)
```

Doing this will show you values that are present in one, but not present in both

```
array_merge(array_diff($b, $a), array_diff($a, $b));
```

so for example

```
$a = array('a','c','b','e','x');
$b = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$difference = array_merge(array_diff($b, $a),array_diff($a, $b));
print_r($difference);

//outputs Array ( [0] => d [1] => f [2] => x )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $a = array('a','c','b','e','x');
    $b = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

    $c=array_diff($a,$b);
    $d=array_diff($b,$a);
    $e=array_merge($c,$d);
    print_r($e);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/94065)

Comment: That doesnt work because you will only get the difference between the first and the second, but not the second and the first. The output is only `Array ( [4] => x ) ` You need to do the comparison twice and chance the params.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/array_diff),

```
$uncommon = array_diff($b,$a) + array_diff($a,$b);
print_r($uncommon);
```

**Output**:

```
Array (
     [3] => d
     [5] => f
     [4] => x 
)
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/rGAZmnun)**.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you difference of the two arrays

```
<?php
$a1 = array('a','c','b','e','x');
$a2 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$difference = array_diff($a1, $a2);

print_r($difference);
?>
```